# How is binary stored on disk

Tags: binary, hexdump, xxd

I have worked with `xxd` utility which translates binary to ascii format and vice versa, but I am not really sure what it dos behind the scene.

Assume I have the following hexdump:

```
0100 0000 0500 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

Clearly this is in ascii format. What is the difference between saving this line on disk as is VS saving it in binary format? how is a single character of `0` stored on disk in ascii VS binary format?

Comment: Save the character `0` in a text file and run it through xxd. `Clearly this is in ascii format.` Yeah, because xxd converted the binary data to a hexadecimal representation. Its not stored in this format though.

Comment: @tkausl what's `0` in binary? does it even make sense to ask this question

Comment: `0` in binary is most likely 48. But thats the _character_ 0 which you see on the screen. The _value_ 0 is literally that, 0.

Comment: @tkausl so what does xxd covert `0` to, can I write in direct binary (and not use xxd for conversion) using the characters on keyboard?

Comment: xxd converts the binary value `0` to the character sequence `00` which is a hexadecimal representation of this value. No, you can't type binary on your keyboard.

Comment: what is xxd doing that I can't type on my keyboard, i'm still lost on that little border between how ascci is translated in to binary

Comment: xxd is doing some math on the numbers to convert them, you can't type them directly. Take a look at the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)